# Why when I run a program in a detached screen section it became very slow?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, gnu-screen, raspberry-pi

I am not so into Linux and I have the following situation related a strange behavior of the **screen** command.

The situation is the following one: one a RaspBerry Pi I have installed **Raspbian** (that is a minimalistic version of **Debian**.

I connect to the RaspBerry using **SSH** and I do the following operations:

1) I create a new **screen** section to run a programm  to keep it running when I off  from ssh. The program is **CPU miner**, a program used to mine BitCoin\LiteCoin and it use a GridSeed that is an USB ASIC hardware that do the work (but I think that this is not so important)

2) I type  **AD** to exit the screen session so I log off from SSH.

The problem is that when I detached the screeb section the performance decrease dramatically. It do exactly a sixth of the work that it do when the section is not detached.

So I have no idea about this behavior and I can think only two thing:

1) When a section is detached the priority of its process is decreased

2) Maybe the RaspBerry hardware is not powerful enough and it can't appropriately handle the process in a detached screen section.

What is the problem? what am I missing? what can I do to solve this issue?

Tnx